# React-router-native: Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.func')

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-router-dom, react-proptypes

i have created a project with react-native. When i install react-router with the command

```
 npm install react-router-native
```

I have the following error: https://prnt.sc/6nzME4AUzGi1

My problem is that i am not using

```
 react.PropTypes.func
```

in my program but this error indicates in node modules.

My code is here:

```
 import { NativeRouter } from "react-router-native";

 const App = () => {
  return (
   <>
     <NativeRouter>
        <Main/>
     </NativeRouter>
    <RepositoryList />
  </>
 )
};
```

My other file:

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<RepositoryList />} exact />
    <Route path="/signIn" element={<SignIn />} exact />
  </Routes>
```

When i am not using

```
 react-router-native
```

my program works fine. There is a problem with my code or is something else?

Comment: Can you check/verify the installed versions of several packages for us? From the project's root directory run `npm list react react-router react-router-dom react-router-native history` and report back the installed versions?

Comment: After running this commands in my root directory, for `npm list react react-router`  [link](https://prnt.sc/QgMOu1OeAZib)

Comment: For the command `npm list react react-router-dom` [link](https://prnt.sc/dgnI9nyo3Kbc) and for the command `npm list react react-router-native history` [link](https://prnt.sc/C4uCFqw0E1kC)    @DrewReese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've a bunch of ***much*** older versions of `react-router` and `history` installed.

`react-router-natve@5.3.2` is installed, but `react-router` is a much older v2 version (*that also isn't compatible with React 17*). Based on the `Route` component API/syntax used you want `react-router@6` *and* `react-router-native@6` installed.

You'll likely want to uninstall those, then install the specific version of `react-router` and `react-router-native`.

Uninstall/install `react-router` and `react-router-native` v6:

```
npm install --save react-router@6 react-router-native@6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just created your react native application you can use the React Navigation library. It is the most common for react native, it is easy to use and the doc is really nice :)

You can check the doc here:

https://reactnavigation.org/